# How to print ALL the discrepencies between two XML documents

Tags: c#, xmlunit

I just discovered this nice tool [XmlUnit](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit.net) that allows me to evaluate 2 different XML documents and display the eventual discrepencies.

```
string control = "<a><b attr=\"abc\"></b></a>";
string test = "<a><b attr=\"xyz\"></b></a>";

var myDiff = DiffBuilder.Compare(Input.FromString(control))
              .WithTest(Input.FromString(test))
              .Build();

Assert.IsFalse(myDiff.HasDifferences(), myDiff.ToString());
```

However, I have found that the  `myDiff.ToString()` only displays the first difference encountered.
Is there a way to display them all ?

Comment: did you try  XML Diff tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution

```
Assert.IsFalse(myDiff.HasDifferences(), string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myDiff.Differences));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the [xmlunit.net](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit.net)  library (You didn't say the name of the tool that you found but your example seems to match).

You can search their GitHub repo and find the [DiffBuilder](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit.net/blob/master/src/main/net-core/Builder/DiffBuilder.cs) class file. If you look at the Build method you will see it returns a Diff object. If you go to the [Diff](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit.net/blob/master/src/main/net-core/Diff/Diff.cs) class file you will find that it's ToString method looks like this.

```
public override string ToString() {
        return ToString(formatter);
}
```

Which doesn't tell you a lot but if you go to the other ToString overload you find this.

```
public string ToString(IComparisonFormatter formatter) {
    if (!HasDifferences()) {
            return "[identical]";
    }
    return differences.First().Comparison.ToString(formatter);
}
```

Now we are getting somewhere. We now know that Diff stores its list of differences in a private differences field and why ToString() only returns one difference (The .First() call). If you look through that class you will find that there's a public property called Differences which exposes that field as an IEnumerable. So the way to get all differences is to loop through that property and collect all of them like so.

```
string control = "<a><b attr=\"abc\" attr2=\"123\"></b></a>";
string test = "<a><b attr=\"xyz\" attr2=\"987\"></b></a>";

var myDiff = DiffBuilder.Compare(Input.FromString(control))
              .WithTest(Input.FromString(test))
              .Build();

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var dif in myDiff.Differences)
{
    sb.AppendLine(dif.Comparison.ToString());
}
Assert.IsFalse(myDiff.HasDifferences(), sb.ToString());
```

Note that I got the syntax for formatting the difference from the Diff class's ToString code. Also notice that I added a second attribute to your examples to demonstrate that this really is showing all the differences.

Comment: Correct, I forgot to mention the tool, I have updated my question and my answer ;-)